# Binding element to a reactive object causes an infinite loop in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I’m having an issue using svelte.

I’m trying to map an object passed as a prop and then use it in an `#each` block.

It works fine until I try to bind the element to the object using `bind:this`. It causes an infinite update loop and freezes the page.

So I’m wondering if it’s me doing something wrong or an issue with svelte.

Here’s the code:

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import InfiniteLoop from "./InfiniteLoop.svelte";
    let data = [1, 2, 3];
</script>

<InfiniteLoop {data} />
```

InfiniteLoop.svelte

```
<script>
    export let data;

    $: mapped = data.map((v) => ({
        value: v,
        element: undefined
    }));
</script>

{#each mapped as m}
    <div>{m.value}</div>
    <!-- Uncommenting this will freeze the page -->
    <!-- <div bind:this={m.element}>{m.value}</div> -->
{/each}
```

Here’s the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/149e541b97c841028dbbcba13809d1c2?version=4.0.5

Making the reactive variable just a const stops the page from freezing, but doesn’t solve my issue.

Comment: You are not meant to do this anyway, the mapped data would be internal to the component. Why are you trying to do this in the first place, what are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I want to update the bound element’s style once every x milliseconds. I can’t invalidate all of the data to update the style since setting up the elements involves some expensive computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in svelte, as the binding is changed it mutates the original array and while the reactive declaration should ignore it, it doesn't.
For reference please loo at here
https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4448
and
https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7704
Some more cases when it breaks:

```
<script>
  import Component from './Component.svelte';
    
    export let emails = ['a@example.com', 'b@example.com'];
    $: set = new Set(emails)
</script>

{#each emails as email}
    <Component email={email} bind:set />
{/each}
```

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4426

The solution would be to change to primitive types or raw variables, or perhaps considering using stores for your arrays/objects.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the bound element’s style once every x milliseconds. I can’t invalidate all of the data to update the style since setting up the elements involves some expensive computation.

You could just use a [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action) instead. Any dependencies (like the `value`) can be passed in.

Alternatively, extract the contents of the `{#each}` to a separate component which gives you a new top level scope in which you can do anything independently from the rest of the data, e.g. update a `style` variable via `setInterval` and just pass that directly to the `div`.

Or wrap the style calculation and interval logic in a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store) attached to the array, then the store's value can be passed to the `style` attribute.

Generally you should not need or use `bind:this` much.